# tlogcatcher component not catching error for tMSSqlRow read error

Tags: sql, try-catch, talend

I develop some jobs with Talend, and use Tlogcatcher to record errors on a database. It seems working for all jobs except one.

[image]

Here is how it work:

The first SQL connection read SQL statement from a database table, and for each of them, the tMSSqlRow read and execute it.

But when SQL failed (i.e delete not possible cause of constraint integrity), the error is not caught by the tLogCatcher component.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tLogCatcher` is not supposed to be used like you did in your job (with `OnComponentError`/`OnSubjobError` triggers), it has to be the first component of an independent subjob (not linked by a trigger) which gets called whenever there is an error/warning/java exception, depending on which types you check in `tLogCatcher` settings.
If you want to keep the `OnComponentError` trigger, you can omit the `tLogCatcher` altogether and just do your error processing in the subjob triggered by `OnComponentError`.
Also, make sure you check "Die on error" option in your tMSSqlRow component, otherwise no error is thrown and the job just prints an error message to the console and continues execution, thus the `tLogCatcher` won't be invoked.

**Edit:**

Based on your requirement (continue job execution on error), a solution would be to encapsulate the processing that happens starting from `tMSSqlRow` onward (as well as the error handling technique I suggested above) in a child job.
This child job needs to define a context parameter (for instance QUERY) and does the processing for this single query. The parent job calls this child job with an `Iterate` trigger, and passing it each query to be processed via the QUERY context parameter (the global variable that is in your `tFlowToIterate` is passed to `QUERY` context parameter in the `tRunJob` parameters tab).
This way, if your query processing in the child job results in an error, it is handled inside the child job by the `tLogCatcher`, and the parent job isn't aware of this error, so it continues to the next query.

Comment: Hi IMezouar, thanks for your feedback. I will try. But if I need the job go on even if some error appears ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to your problem. Please let me know if you need more help putting it together, or accept my answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that.

regards